# Backup and Restore Failure

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, restore

I am trying to backup using the default "Backup and Restore" in Windows 7 onto a Western Digital Passport and it is never able to complete.

This error appears about a third of the way into the process: [image]

Comment: What is logged in the System event log around the time the backup fails?

Answer (score 0):

This may be because reparse point or mounted volumes are added in your backup include list. The below kb article explains this error:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973455/en-us

You can use the fsutil command to verify if there are any reparse points in your backup path.

fsutil reparsepoint query

Comment: What is a reparse point?

Comment: An NTFS reparse point is a type of NTFS file system object. It is available with the NTFS v3.0 found in Windows 2000 or later versions. Reparse points provide a way to extend the NTFS filesystem. A reparse point contains a reparse tag and data that are interpreted by a filesystem filter identified by the tag. Microsoft includes several default tags including NTFS symbolic links, directory junction points and volume mount points.

Answer (score -1):

Go to restart the Volume Shadow Copy service and SPP service. Note: you have to login as administrator to perform this.
Then according to the error code and message, it may related to the Microsoft's Security Essentials version 2.
Security Essentials includes ‘real time protection’ to scan and detect viruses on your hard drive and will quarantine or an infected file, as a result the use of real time protection prevents the backup from completing.

More specifically, viruses that are not detected (for whatever reason) before a backup is started will be detected during the actual backup as is the case of Security Essential’s ‘real time protection’. However even though the ‘History’ log will show the infected file as being ‘Removed’ it is in fact only removed from the “VolumeShadowCopy” created during the backup process and not removed from the actual location of the hard disk. Therefore attempting another backup will only result in another backup failure.

**The solution:**
Before starting a backup (manual or schedule) is to run a “Full” scan of your hard drive as a simple “Quick” scan may not detect the infected file depending on its location on your hard drive. Set the option as to what to do with infected files to ‘Remove’, do not quarantine the file as this may not be sufficient.
https://www.pagestart.com/win7br0x8100003701.html